# Objects nested in objects iteration?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that will find the Categoy[3].options[3].label and matches it to the letter "D".

How do I iterate through the nested objects below to go through the TagCategory.options and search for the option that matches to the letter "D"? If it matches the letter "D", it should return true.

```
"Category": 
[
  {
      "field": "A", 
      "options": [
          {"tag": "100", "value": "yes"}
      ], 
      "label": "Red"
  }, 

  {
      "field": "tanks", 
      "type": true, 
      "options": [
          {"tag_value": "4", "value": "4", "label": "A"}, 
          {"tag_value": "3", "value": "3", "label": "B"}, 
          {"tag_value": "2", "value": "2", "label": "C"}, 
          {"tag_value": "1", "value": "1", "label": "D"}, 
          {"tag_value": "5", "value": "5", "label": "E"}
      ], 
      "label": "Tanks"
  }
]
```

Comment: there is no `TagCategories` property?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @shadow I''m having trouble trying to figure out how to access object values nested in other objects so I don't know how to best write a function for that

Comment: Have you considered a nested for loop?

Comment: @shadow can you provide an example?

Comment: Are you trying to check if an object has a property `"label"` which has a `value` `"D"`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, I am

Comment: @sk_225 I've written up an example as requested http://stackoverflow.com/a/41274168/1594286

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function findLabel(arr, label) {

  for (var i in arr) {
    const options = arr[i].options;
    const find = options.find(o => o.label == label);
    if (find) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;

}

const test = findLabel(Category, "D");
```

Category is your array

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(category, letter){
  var obj;
  var optionObj;
  for(var i = 0; i < category.length; i++){
    obj = Category[i];
      options = obj.options;
      for(var j = 0; j < options.length; j++){
        optionObj = option[j];
        if(optionObj.label === letter) return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.some()`

```
let optionHasLabelDBool = obj.Category.some(({options}) =>   
                            options.some(({label}) => label === "D"));
```

```js
let obj = {
    "Category":
      [{
          "field": "A",
          "options": [{
            "tag": "100",
            "value": "yes"
          }],
          "label": "Red"
        },

        {
          "field": "tanks",
          "type": true,
          "options": [{
            "tag_value": "4",
            "value": "4",
            "label": "A"
          }, {
            "tag_value": "3",
            "value": "3",
            "label": "B"
          }, {
            "tag_value": "2",
            "value": "2",
            "label": "C"
          }, {
            "tag_value": "1",
            "value": "1",
            "label": "D"
          }, {
            "tag_value": "5",
            "value": "5",
            "label": "E"
          }],
          "label": "Tanks"
        }
      ]
    };
  
let optionHasLabelD = obj.Category.some(({options}) => options.some(({label}) => label === "D"));

console.log(optionHasLabelD);
```

Using a function, without arrow function or object destructing

```
function checkOption(array, prop, key, value) {
  return array.some(function(obj) {
    return obj[prop].some(function(match) {
      return match[key] === value;
    });
  });
}

let optionHasLabelDBool = checkOption(obj.Category, "options", "label", "D");
```

```js
let obj = {
  "Category": [{
      "field": "A",
      "options": [{
        "tag": "100",
        "value": "yes"
      }],
      "label": "Red"
    },

    {
      "field": "tanks",
      "type": true,
      "options": [{
        "tag_value": "4",
        "value": "4",
        "label": "A"
      }, {
        "tag_value": "3",
        "value": "3",
        "label": "B"
      }, {
        "tag_value": "2",
        "value": "2",
        "label": "C"
      }, {
        "tag_value": "1",
        "value": "1",
        "label": "D"
      }, {
        "tag_value": "5",
        "value": "5",
        "label": "E"
      }],
      "label": "Tanks"
    }
  ]
};


function checkOption(array, prop, key, value) {
  return array.some(function(obj) {
    return obj[prop].some(function(match) {
      console.log(match[key], value, match[key] === value);
      return match[key] === value;
    });
  });
}

let optionHasLabelDBool = checkOption(obj.Category, "options", "label", "D");

console.log(optionHasLabelDBool);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough example of what I mean by a nested for loop.

```
category = {...}; // your object above
for (i in category) {
    field = category[i];
    for (option_i in field.options) {  
        // This is the nested for loop - called thus because it's inside one.
        if (field.options[option_i].label == "D"){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```